# How to compare two dates time hours and minutes

Tags: javascript, date

The date sent from server (in request) has the following format: '05-02-2024 10:20'

How to compare this date with the current date?

Example of an (unsuccessful) attempt:

```
checkDate(){
  const current = new Date().getTime();
  const dateSentFromServer = '05-02-2024 10:20';
  const myDate = Date.parse(dateSentFromServer);

  if (myDate > current) {
      return false;
  } else {
      return true;
  }
}
```

EDITED:

A simple example for better description:

A post can only be seen by the user on a certain date registered in the database in a specific format (05-02-2024 10:20)

To do this, it is necessary to check whether this date has already been verified by comparing it with the current date

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "How to compare this date with the current date?"

Comment: `dateSentFromServer` cant be acceptable, there is no time zone value. direct date-time comparison can only done with utc+0 values.

Comment: @Scott Hunter i edited my post

Comment: @Mister Jojo thanks. I will try with your suggestion

Comment: `parse` expects your date to be formatted as `2024-05-02T10:20:00`.

Comment: And if you have the opportunity to fix it now, send a standard date/time format (with TZ) such as ISO8601 rather than a wholly ambiguous format such as "05-02-2024 10:20".

Comment: @jarmod. Thanks. The problem is actually in the date  format. I will have to explore the possibility of getting the date from the server in another format (if feasible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see if a timestamp before or after "now", then simply parse it and compare it to `Date.now()`, e.g.

```js
let timestamp = '05-02-2024 10:20';

// Parse timestamp as day-month-year hour:min
let [d,m,y,hr,min] = timestamp.split(/\D+/);

// Is 5 Feb 2024 before now?
console.log(new Date(y, m-1, d, hr, min) < Date.now());
```

You may wish to create a separate function (or use a library) to do the parse.